# SSIS Data Flow Task Error for Flat File: Source Potential Metadata corruption during Validation

Tags: ssis, business-intelligence, sql-server-data-tools

I'm getting the following error in SSIS Data Tools 2013 when adding a Flat file source to Data Flow task. Tried adding it to new and already existing SSIS packages, not working in either cases.

> ### TITLE: Editing Component
>
> The component has detected potential metadata corruption during
>   validation. Error at Data Flow Task [Flat File Source [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDivR.png)]: Failed to
>   find any non-special error column in Flat File Source.Outputs[Flat
>   File Source Error Output].
>
> It may not be possible to recover to a valid state using a
>   component-specific editor. Do you want to use the Advanced Editor
>   dialog box for editing this component?

[image]
Could not find any solution on the web.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions could be creating a new solution. It did work for me. But still not sure if there is a walk-around when need to add a flat file source to a data flow task in the existing project.

Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

SSIS > Un-check "Work Offline"

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by deleting the flat file source from the data flow section and adding it back.